# Extracting Sinhala Characters from a PDF File using PDFTextStream

Tags: java, pdf, unicode

I'm trying to get the content of a pdf which is in Sinhala (eg-: http://archives.dailynews.lk/2001/pix/GazetteS14-01-03.pdf).

I saved pdf in computer and used following code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.snowtide.pdf.OutputTarget;
import com.snowtide.pdf.PDFTextStream;

public class ExtractTextAllPages {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String pdfFilePath = "/home/chamila/semester7/fyp/gazette/GazetteS14-01-03.pdf";
        PDFTextStream pdfts = new PDFTextStream(pdfFilePath); 
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(1024);
        pdfts.pipe(new OutputTarget(text));
        pdfts.close();
        System.out.printf("The text extracted from %s is:", pdfFilePath);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

But what I get as output is something like following.

```
Y%S ,xld m%cd;dka;%sl iudcjd§ ckrcfha .eiÜ m;%h                 1
wxl 1"844 – 2014 ckjdß ui 03 jeks isl=rdod – 2014'01'03

^rcfha n,hmsg m%isoaO lrk ,§'&

I jeks fldgi : ^IIw& jeks fPoh - m<lsÍï
;k;=re - wenE3;=

                 Y%S ,xld fmd,sia fomd3;fïka;=j
.............................
```

What is the reason for this? How can I get the exact content in pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *What is the reason for this*

The document in question simply does not contain the information for proper text extraction. Even worse, it contains misleading information.

### For example

The head line

[image]

is generated using these operators:

```
BT
/TT4 1 Tf
19.2 0 0 32 184.205 938.105 Tm
-0.0006 Tc
0.1376 Tw
(Y%S ,xld m%cd;dka;%sl iudcjd§ ckrcfha .eiÜ m;%h) Tj
ET
```

(i.e. using the font **TT4** the sequence `Y%S ,xld m%cd;dka;%sl iudcjd§ ckrcfha .eiÜ m;%h` is drawn at some position in some size using a certain character and word spacing.)

The font **TT4** now claims to be:

```
/Subtype/TrueType
/FontDescriptor 66 0 R
/LastChar 255
/Widths[...]
/BaseFont/CKAKNH+FMAbabldBold
/FirstChar 32
/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding
/Type/Font
```

i.e. a **TrueType** font using **WinAnsiEncoding** without a **ToUnicode** mapping.

Thus, text extractors are made believe that the sequence `Y%S ,xld m%cd;dka;%sl iudcjd§ ckrcfha .eiÜ m;%h` drawn as headline represents the *characters* "Y%S ,xld m%cd;dka;%sl iudcjd§ ckrcfha .eiÜ m;%h", and so PDFTextStream returns you that string.

The fact that the displayed glyphs show different characters is due to the embedded font file having graphic drawing instructions for those glyphs which look completely unlike "Y%S ,xld m%cd;dka;%sl iudcjd§ ckrcfha .eiÜ m;%h".

## *How can I get the exact content in pdf?*

Use OCR.

Comment: A decoding (string replaces) is not possible?

Comment: *A decoding (string replaces) is not possible?* - Well, you can, of course, create a program which first shows each glyph of each embedded font to a human who then enters the matching character; afterwards that program may extract the page content automatically using character replacement with the information given by the human. Beware, though: each font may have its own actual encoding, and fonts may be defined on a per-page basis.

Comment: Furthermore font files can contain information on the correct character of a glyph, so maybe by looking at the embedded fonts a program can get those information, too. But don't count on that, fonts embedded into PDFs often are stripped down to the bare essentials, and the mapping glyph->character is not an essential.

Answer (score 0):

According to the snowtide documentation  (http://downloads.snowtide.com/javadoc/PDFTextStream/2.3.2/index.html?pdfts/examples/XMLFormExport.html ) , PDFTextStream supports all single-byte and double-byte Unicode character sets.

Most of the sinhala characters are in three bytes as i know. that will be the problem

Comment: *that will be the problem* - no, see my answer, the PDF claims false information concerning the glyphs drawn.